# How to compare two strings in a cell on Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am trying to find a way to look at a cell in a spreadsheet and see if the next value equals that value...
this is my current code:

```
function BTB(name,ng) {
  if(typeof(name) == typeof(ng)) {
    var c = '0';
    Logger.log(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "next value?"  The cell to the right?  The cell underneath?  The new value that is replacing the old value that was just edited?

Comment: Sorry the value to the right, and below

Comment: Why are you using typeof?

Comment: How are calling the function? How are you assigning values/objects to the function arguments?

Comment: I currently have 2 functions in 1 cell and this is just 1 of them. I assign the values through referencing two different cells for example: BTB(C10,D10)

Comment: The function isn't complete. Please checkout [Custom functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Answer (score 0):

It is a good habit to use meaningful names for functions and variables, so I renamed your `BTB()` to `compare()`. Also, instead of passing arguments, I took the liberty of just using the active cell. Hope it works! please let me know after trying the code below:

```
function compare() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveCell(), msg,
      equal = (cell.getValue() === cell.offset(1, 1).getValue()); // to the right and below
  if (equal) msg = 'active cell is same as next'
  else msg = 'active cell is different from next';
  Browser.msgBox(msg)
}
```

By the way, the code above makes the difference between '2' (string) and 2 (number) thanks to the strict equal sign, `===`.